# Setting Enum values with variables

Tags: c#, enums, constants

The following doesn't work because w and h need to be `const's`. I'm assuming `Enums` have to be set at compile time and can't be changed at run time. Is this a possibility, or is it better to just make foo a class?

```
class Bar 
{
    int w, h;
    enum foo : int 
    { 
        a = w * h 
    }

    public Bar(int w, int h) 
    {
         this.w = w;
         this.h = h;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, `enum` member definitions must be compile time constants. Whether  or not `foo` is better suited to be a class  depends entirely upon how you're going to use it, really.

Comment: Enumerations shouldn't derive from `int` explicitly: they already do it implicitly...

Comment: Your ideas regarding how to use enums seem quite unclear. Here you have an example which might be helpful: `enum myFirstInts { one, two, three }` which you can use like `myFirstInts myFirstEnumVar = myFirstInts.one;` or even `myFirstInts myFirstEnumVar = 0;` (-> it refers to one).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not completely getting the idea of enums in c#. Take a look at the C# Reference ([here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032.aspx))

> The enum keyword is used to declare an enumeration, a distinct type that consists of a set of named constants called the enumerator list.

You **cannot** assign variables to an enum. You should be looking at another structure.

Answer (score 0):

as you say, you can't: an enum must be defined at compile time, not at runtime.
Don't go with a different class, just make foo a read only property:

```
public int foo
{
    get
    {
         return w*a;
    }
}
```

Comment: foo will actually hold more than one value. That's why its an enum in the first place. ignore the fact the pseudo code only holds one value. So although the answer is technically correct, the example doesn't solve my problem.